# Finding the index of max value based on another list in python

Tags: python, max

Could someone help me with this part of my code? I don't know how I should code the comment part of the below code.

```
p = [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
ed = [(1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (3,2)]

for (i,j) in ed:
    if i=1:

# the j for i= 1 would be 3 and 4 since I have (1,3) and (1,4) in "ed".
# I want to chose maximum between j, so in this case the maximum is 4.
# then considering list "p" I want to know the index of the j (here is 4) in the list "p"
#so the expected outcome must be 3 since the index of 4 in the list p is 3.
```

Comment: im sorry but your comment doesn't make sense , provide better explanation and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana Thank for your comment. I tried to better explain  what I want to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
p = [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
ed = [(1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (3,2)]

i = 1

print(p.index(max([num[1] for num in ed if num[0] == i])))
```

output:

```
>>>
3
```

be aware this would through error if no tuple could be find in ed or the number can't be find in p. so you might wanna handle those situations

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.